# Laravel case insensitive localization

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, laravel-5

Is it possible to make laravel case insensitive against trans statements? for example return the same translated term for both `Action` and `action` :

```
  lang/trans_form.php 

return [
 'Action' => 'اقدامات',

 //I'm not happy with writing this one,it would be better if laravel do it itself!
 'action' => 'اقدامات',
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the `Translator` class and use it within the another extended `TranslationServiceProvider` class.

Lets say, we will store it in `app/Extended` folder.

Create an extended translator class like below. Just change the key to lowercase and pass it to the parent.

```
<?php

namespace App\Extended;

use Illuminate\Translation\Translator;

class ExtendedTranslator extends Translator
{
    public function get($key, array $replace = [], $locale = null, $fallback = true)
    {
        $key = mb_strtolower($key);
        return parent::get($key, $replace, $locale, $fallback);
    }
}
```

Then use our newly created extended Translator class within the extended TranslationServiceProvider,

```
<?php

namespace App\Extended;

use Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider;

class ExtendedTranslationServiceProvider extends TranslationServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerLoader();
        $this->app->singleton('translator', function ($app) {
            $loader = $app['translation.loader'];
            $locale = $app['config']['app.locale'];
            $trans = new ExtendedTranslator($loader, $locale);
            $trans->setFallback($app['config']['app.fallback_locale']);
            return $trans;
        });
    }
}
```

Finally, register the extended ExtendedTranslationServiceProvider instead of the original one within the `config/app.php`.

```
'providers' => [
    // Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    App\Extended\ExtendedTranslationServiceProvider::class,
]
```

Comment: hello there, how does laravel know that it has to use this class instead of the default one? shouldn't we bind it with some interface for example?... i mean, at least on laravel 6.x it doesn't work properly